# Emailing in C# why isn't the information sending correctly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, formatting

I have a form that the users for my website will fill out.  Once they click submit the information they filled out is supposed to be sent to my email.  For some reason the information they fill out is not being sent.  I am posting the code below.  For a while it was working, but I must have changed something simple when I was trying to get other parts of the code to work and now I can't figure it out.

```
 protected void Submit_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {


            string strMessage = "Bug Name: " + txtBugName.Text.Trim() 
                                             + "<br/>" + "Module Name: " + ddlModule.SelectedValue 
                                             + "<br/>" + "Page Name: " + ddlPage.SelectedValue 
                                             + "<br/>" + "Description: " + txtComments.Text.Trim() 

                                             + "<br/>" + "Email is" + " " + txtemail.Text.Trim() 
                                             + "<br/>" + "The request was sent at" +   



            SendMessage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddrTo"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailAddrFrom"],
                txtBugName.Text.Trim(),
                strMessage, "", "");
        }
        catch 
        {

        }
    }
```

As you can see I have this code pulling the information they fill out and then also I am formatting it for the email that will be sent to myself.  But now I just get a blank email or actually the subject line will have something,  but the email will be blank.

Also at the bottom of the code you can see i put this email was sent at + dandt I am trying to have the date and time sent in that part is there any code I can just put there to send the date and time the email was sent at?  Like is there any syntax specifically just for date and time?

Thank you all

Comment: Remove the empty catch block to see the error, and what does the SendMessage method do?

Comment: The OP did get (empty) e-mails, so something *did* get sent. So I expect no exception.

Comment: @IrishChieftain - I didn't change your answer into a comment. You are right about not swallowing the exception, it's just that that is not the problem at this moment (I think :-) ). We need to see that SendMessage method.

Comment: Correct, but as he starts changing the method signature he may create one as he gets order of params correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're swallowing the exception. Remove the try/catch to see any errors that may occur as you change your code; only apply exception handling after testing.

Verify your method signature (params) here because that's where the mistake lies:

UPDATE:

You need to pass the parameters in the following order (read the link below):

```
public void Send(
    string from,
    string to,
    string subject,
    string body
)
```

[SmtpClient.Send Method (String, String, String, String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h1s04he7.aspx)

Comment: The OP did get (empty) e-mails, so something *did* get sent. So I expect no exception.

Comment: @Hans, updated my answer to explain why the try/catch should be temporarily removed :)

Comment: I am so confused about what you mean for me to do here.  Sorry I am new to coding only started a few months ago and put this code together mostly watching tutorials online and reading examples.  So I do not even fully understand the code I put together.  Can you please further explain what it is you told me to do here.  Either way thank you so much for taking your time to help me your a good guy.

Comment: You are passing your parameters in the wrong order, am updating answer.

Comment: You strMessage string is also incorrectly formed - no trailing semi-colon;

Answer (score 0):

Your wrote the following, with extra strings snipped:

```
string strMessage = "..." + ... + SendMessage(..., strMessage, ...);
```

You're calling `SendMessage()` before assigning `strMessage`.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, buy this what do i need to change?

Comment: @user1486774: You need to call `SendMessage()` **after** setting the string.

Comment: Ok thank you so much I hopefully will be able to figure it out